# How to display file system in an air application?

Tags: air, flex4, filesystems

I'm working on a file sharing application. I want to display a client file system on one side and on other side i.e server(or peer's) file system, so that they can transfer files from one system to another by dragging and dropping.

Now, I want to display my local file system as it opens main window without any browse or search buttons. Its a windowed application doing in Adobe Flash Builder. Can any body help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.flex-blog.com/list-directory-with-air-in-flex-4/) found with a single Google search.

Comment: Thank you, Threatrus. Already I found this sample but here,it does not open the folder and I want let user drag and drop files/folders/images one system to another. I want to display the file system as a tree and file manipulation can be done.